# RestTemplate throwing generic 400 Bad Request, but custom server sent message is not is lost

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

We have a rest controller API with POST mapping which takes an object as request param and creates the same on DB. We have got few validations on the input object, and if there is any error, then we are throwing exception with a custom message.

If we invoke this API from post man, we see the appropriate error.

Whereas when we invoke this in the caller method of other application with Spring's RestTemplate, all we see is a 400 Bad request with empty body. No error message is seen.

What could be the issue here. How can we get the custom message thrown from the API.

Here is how we are calling the API with rest template.

```
    String url = "https://localhost:8895/servuceUrl";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<AddRequest> entity = new HttpEntity<AddRequest>(obj, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> data = null;
    adddata = restTemplate.exchange(syncurl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

And one server side we have an exception written as

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class InvalidDataException extends Exception {


    public InvalidDataException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

The controller looks like

```
@PostMapping(RestUriMappings.POST_MAPPING)
public ResponseDto add(@Valid @RequestBody AddRequest data) throws InvalidDataException 
{

    logger.debug("Incoming data for add: {}", data.toString());

    // validate the payload
    if(data.getName()==null)
       throw new InvalidDataException("Name shouldnt be null");
}
```

Comment: Did you try call String body = data.getBody()? Are the body still empty?

Comment: Do you set the same media type header in POSTMAN as well or not?

Answer (score 7):

Spring's RestTemplate implementation has kind of a weird functionality. Whenever, the response is a 4XX, it throws a `HttpClientErrorException` instead of returning the response. Similarly, when the response is a 5XX response, it throws a `HttpServerErrorException`.

When you go inside the library, you will come across the piece of code which is responsible for such functionality inside `DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java#handleError(ClientHttpResponse response)`.

So, if you want to fetch the original 4XX or 5XX response, you would have to write a wrapper over the `RestTemplate.java#exchange()` method. Something like this-

```
private ResponseEntity<String> exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> httpEntity,
                                           Class<?> class1, Map<String, String> paramMap) {
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;
        try {
            responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, httpEntity, String.class, paramMap);
        }catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
            responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }catch(HttpServerErrorException e) {
            responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            throw e;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            throw e;
        }
        return responseEntity;
    }
```

Comment: Any specific reason to do that by Spring's RestTemplate ?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question but if you are asking why Spring's Rest Template throws an exception in the case of 4XX and 5XX, the reason probably is because for most people 4XX and 5XX are erroneous scenarios and should not ideally occur on production. Throwing an exception would result in less/no handling required on the part of the developer for most use cases and hence the creators of Spring probably wanted the same. However, for most production-grade applications, these exceptions have to be handled and mapped with specific responses as per API contracts.

Comment: Yes that is my question and clear you idea. But I think if 4XX and 5XX scenarios handle  as ResponseEntities all status codes can handle in same way. These exceptions are RuntimeExceptions, so they don't identify in compile time. These points may miss to developers as I understood.

Comment: You are not wrong, we missed it as well the first time we implemented it

Comment: I replace RestTemplate from WebClient and webTestClient. It has expected behavior. Are you plan to change RestTemplate in future versions or keep current implementation ?

Comment: No plans as of now

Answer (score 0):

You are missing:

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Mukul Bansal's answer I did following modification.

```
public class MyErrorHandler extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    protected void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response, HttpStatusCode statusCode) throws IOException {

    }

}
```

Override handleError method without any content.

Then set error handler to RestTemplate.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
```

Then it return ResponseEntity with actual status code.

Anyway I cannot understand reason for default Spring's implementation.